# Add columns based on row index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pd dataframe with sentiments 'Bullish' and 'Bearish' on different dates. I counted the number of sentiments in a new column. Now I want to create two new columns, one is 'Bullish' and another is 'Bearish' so that it can count how many sentiments appeared in such dates. [Now the output looks like this. As you can see, there may have both 'Bullish' and 'Bearish' on the same date. And it is hard to do analysis in this form. I want to create two new columns to separate the 'Bullish' and 'Bearish'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzpC0.png)

So for example, for the date 08/01/2014, my expected result is that there is a number 8 in the new column 'Bullish' and a number 1 in the new column 'Bearish' at the same row.

Any ideas on this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please review [ask] and create a [mcve], that means no images of code!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply unstack the 'sentN' level in your index:

```
df.unstack('sentN')
```

I hope it helped !